# Logging ssh info using syslog-ng daemon in Cygwin

Tags: ssh, windows-7, unix, syslog, cygwin

I have setup the syslog-ng daemon using Cygwin in Windows 7. What I want to do is to log all of the ssh failed passwords, etc to `/var/log/sshd.log`. I tried to do this by adding the following line:

```
auth.* /var/log/sshd.log
```

to `/etc/syslog.conf`

However, all the ssh info gets logged to `/var/log/messages` and `sshd.log` is empty.
I have been searching net for long time, but cant find a solution. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the old sysklogd conf file syntax (and file path).

Syslog-ng looks (by default) at /etc/syslog-ng.conf

The manpage for that file is here: http://linux.die.net/man/5/syslog-ng.conf

A basic filter for ssh messages to go to a separate file would look like

```
destination ssh { file("/var/log/ssh.log"); };
filter f_ssh { program("sshd"); };
log { source(src); filter(f_ssh); destination(ssh); };
```

in /etc/syslog-ng.conf

Answer (score 0):

[HERE](http://techtorials.me/cygwin/logging/) are some more details setting up Syslog-ng.